# How to write two functions horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

If I want to write two functions *`f`* and *`g`* vertically in the center of the page I will write like this:

```
\begin{align*}
\f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in A \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in B \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
```

How I write this two functions horizontally, one in the left end another one in the right end ?

Comment: @ Count Zero: How u do this?

Comment: You could put them in a `minipage`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, should've posted that... `:)` If you have inline code, use backticks: `. Alternatively, backticks can be applied to selections with Ctrl+K. If you have full code blocks, either indent every line with 4 spaces or select the block and use the button with the braces above the edit the edit window.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As egreg pointed out, since you are not have any alignment points for the `align` environment, you could simply use `gather*` (or `equation*` since you are converting to a one line equation):

[image]

### Notes:

- You should also have a look at the `cases` (and `dcases` if using `mathtools` package).
- There should never be two subsequent display math equations without some text in between, and you should not leave a blank line (a commented line is fine) between display math environments.  Otherwise there is too much vertical space.
- You can use `\text{}` as well to get to upright roman text in math mode (with `amsmath`).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

% Not sure what these are defined as so adjust as desired
\newcommand*{\f}{F}%
\newcommand*{\g}{G}%

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in A \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right.
\quad
\g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in B \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right.
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

If you have multiple lines of equations and do require horizontal alignment points, then this can also be done with the `align` environment.

### Notes:

- The `align` environment provides multiple `rl` pairs of equations with spaces between them.
- The `alignat` environment provides multiple `rl` pairs *without* spaces so spaces would need to be inserted if so desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

% Not sure what these are defined as so adjust as desired
\newcommand*{\f}{F}%
\newcommand*{\g}{G}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in A \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right. &&
\g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
                1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in B \\
                2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `align*` do that can't be done by `gather*` (changing `&&` into a spacing command)?

Comment: And `equation*` is best, obviously. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the others have been faster and posted the solutions with `align` and `alignat`, I will post the one with `minipages` (as suggested by Peter Grill). `:)`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

%with minipages

\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\[
f(x) = \begin{cases}
                1 & \textnormal{if $x\in A$} \\
                2 & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{cases}
            \]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\[
g(x) =  \begin{cases}
                1 & \text{if $x\in B$} \\
                2 & \textnormal{otherwise}
            \end{cases}
            \]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I slightly modified your code (it does not compile - see `\f` and `\g`...) and also used `cases` instead of `array`.

Answer (score 2):

If "horizontally" in this case means side by side, you can use the `alignat*` environment from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)« (here loaded by »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« from the »[mh](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh)« bundle).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    f(x)&=\left\{
    \begin{array}{lll}
      1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in A \\
      2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
    \end{array}
    \right.
    &\qquad
    g(x)&=\left\{
    \begin{array}{lll}
      1 & \textnormal{if} & x\in B \\
      2 & \textnormal{} & \textnormal{otherwise}
    \end{array}
    \right.
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```